# How do I add CSS script to my basic offline html site?

Tags: html, css, button, dreamweaver, classname

Im using [css button generator](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/) to create the code for my css button and it generates the css code and the html code used to insert the css code. But I don't what classname to use. I tried

```
<a href="CSS code/Button1.css" class="classname"></a>
```

But that shows up blank in the website preview.

And for an offline site with minimal design would it be better to put the buttons inline? The site will be put on a CD. I'm using dreamweaver cs6.

Comment: That's not how you add `CSS` to the page. That's just a link to a CSS file. You need to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-your-stylesheet.css">` inside the `<head>` tag
`

Comment: Here is the new code in the site's code 

`</style>
<!--css code-->
<link href="CSS code/Button1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--end of css code-->
</head>`

But it won't show anything different on the page. I'm new to html and css so I apologise for this

Comment: Providing the stylesheet path is correct, you should just be able to add `<a href="#" class="classname">My link</a>` to your HTML, and it should add the styles.

Comment: This just added a hyperlinked text called MY Link, that highlighted red when hovered over.

Comment: It works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/VrVx5/ Are you sure that the path to the CSS file is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Well i guess you will need to learn basic HTML first. Each HTML document should contain HEAD and BODY tags. In HEAD section you link your CSS file or write your generated CSS style between STYLE tags. Something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.button1 {font-size:15px; color: #cccccc; ....}
.button2 {font-size:18px; padding:10px; ...}
</style>
```

or link your CSS file inside HTML header with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/your-stylesheet.css">
```

You can also check here for some basic examples of HTML and structure of HTML documents. 
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

With your link you just make a link to your CSS style which will open as a plain text in browser window so you don't really include it. So include CSS style in your HEAD section either by link or to put your CSS classes and everything between STYLE tags. Once you will do this "call" your style in your links like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="button1">Go to Google</a>
<a href="/path/to/local_file.html" class="button2">Local file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Got it to work. I found this question and answer: [mmo-champion.com](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1213717-CSS-Button-and-Dreamweaver) and it made it clear what you guys were saying.

I deleted the `<style type="text/css">` and made sure that the class was = to "classname" since that was what it was called in the CSS file because it was unchanged, and then it worked. I think it didn't work because I had the class = "button1" and I also didn't delete that bit of code before.

```
<a href="Button1.css" class="classname">Gantt charts & project diary</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
<sub>(source: [css-tricks.com](https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ie-only-css.gif))</sub>
 
One more thing, because Internet Explorer does not support some elements which work on Chrome or FireFox, there are some special codes for including only IE CSS file (file that works only if IE is identified):

For all the IE versions, use this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For X version only:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css">
<![endif]-->
```

** This code can only be used for IE7. If you want to use the CSS code for other IE version, change "7" in the line `!--[if IE 7>` to the appropriate version number.

For IE5.5:

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

For IE6 and lower (including IE6), use `if lte IE 6` or `if lt IE 7`.

For IE7 and higher (including IE7), use `if gte IE 8` or `if gt IE 7`.

Sometimes IE blocks webpages' scripts or ActiveX controls. 
[image]
To ignore IE block scripts or ActiveX controls, use this line, at the head of the HTML code. 
NOT in the `<head>` tags, at the first line. It's important.

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

To read more about this error, read **[MOTW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537628(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**.